# Is there an analytic function for count in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

```
select manager, count(*) over (partition by manager) cnt
from dbtable
group by manager
```

This will provide me the count of manager but if I need a count of senior_manager how will I get it?

```
|--------------------|------------------|
|      Manager       |Senior_Manager    |  
|--------------------|------------------|
|      John          |Arpit             |
|      John          |govind            |
|      John          |olive             |
|      Domnic        |kelvin            |
|      Domnic        |paul              |
|--------------------|------------------|
```

Result

```
John 3
Domnic 2
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is a "senior manager" for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns "1" for all managers -- because it counts the number of rows *after* the `group by`.

If you want to count the number of rows in the table for a given manager, then you want *aggregation*, not *analytic* functions:

```
Select manager, count(*) as cnt
from dbtable
group by manager;
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but it at least addresses the issue that the your query does not do much that is useful.

EDIT:

For the revised question, it simply seems:

```
Select senior_manager, count(*) as cnt
from dbtable
group by senior_manager;
```

Comment: I agree but i need count of senior_manager under this manager. See my table above

Answer (score 0):

The result you wanted can be retrieved by

```
select manager, count(*) over (partition by manager) cnt
from dbtable
```

This means each manager will be associated with the count of rows in the partition where {manager} value equals that  exact manager. According to the table above this is what you expect to get.

Answer (score 0):

Your example:

```
select manager, count(*) over (partition by manager) cnt
from dbtable
group by manager
```

Yields the following results:

```
MANAGER CNT
Domnic  1
John    1
```

If you drop the group by, you get:

```
MANAGER CNT
Domnic  2
Domnic  2
John    3
John    3
John    3
```

Are those the counts you're looking for? If so, then you can eliminate the duplicate rows with distinct:

```
select distinct manager, count(*) over (partition by manager) cnt
from dbtable
```

Which gives:

```
MANAGER CNT
John    3
Domnic  2
```